# How to increment with the new value when on duplicate key?

Tags: mysql

I am using this statement to insert or update on duplicate key.

```
INSERT INTO `tblrequests` (`request_user_id`, `request_rest_item_id`, `request_amount`) VALUES (select f1,f2,f3 from tbltmb)
 on duplicate key
 update `request_amount`=values(`request_amount`);
```

but what i need is to update the current original field to be originalvalue + newvalue 
like this:

```
INSERT INTO `tblrequests` (`request_user_id`, `request_rest_item_id`, `request_amount`) VALUES (23, 7, 3)
 on duplicate key
 update `request_amount`=values(`old_request_amount` + `new_request_amount`);
```

is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naively thinking, he syntax can be different, depending on whether you're doing a `insert ... select` or an `insert ... values`. But don't make any assumptions until you read up ;)

**`insert ... select` case:**

This is easy. Every field has its distinct field name which can be used in the `update` expression, and mysql is smart enough to figure out what/if to update when multiple rows are being inserted.

```
INSERT INTO `tblrequests` 
  (`request_user_id`, `request_rest_item_id`, `request_amount`) 
SELECT f1,f2,f3 from tbltmp
 on duplicate key
 update `request_amount`=`request_amount`+`f3`;
```

**`insert ... values` case:**

Well, to insert a single row, and since you know the corresponding value beforehand, it should be staightforward:

```
INSERT INTO `tblrequests` 
  (`request_user_id`, `request_rest_item_id`, `request_amount`) 
VALUES (23, 7, 3)
 on duplicate key
 update `request_amount`=`request_amount`+3;
```

See? We only add `3`, since it's a constant, known value. But don't get used to that syntax! Consider this:

```
INSERT INTO `tblrequests` 
  (`request_user_id`, `request_rest_item_id`, `request_amount`) 
VALUES (23, 7, 3),(35,10,23),(2,4,99)
```

Although the values are known beforehand, the amount we should add is not constant anymore, because it's different for each row inserted.

**The general syntax**

Luckily, there's a more general syntax to cover all cases:

```
on duplicate key
update request_amount=request_amount+values(request_amount);
```

`values(request_amount)` simply means *"the value I'm trying to put inside the `request_amount` field, for each row, **whatever that corresponds to**"*. This is destionation-oriented, thus independent of whether the source is a `select` or a series of constant tuples. So the above queries would be rewritten as:

```
INSERT INTO `tblrequests` 
  (`request_user_id`, `request_rest_item_id`, `request_amount`) 
SELECT f1,f2,f3 from tbltmp
 on duplicate key
 update `request_amount`=`request_amount`+values(`request_amount`);

INSERT INTO `tblrequests` 
  (`request_user_id`, `request_rest_item_id`, `request_amount`) 
VALUES (23, 7, 3)
 on duplicate key
 update `request_amount`=`request_amount`+values(`request_amount`);

INSERT INTO `tblrequests` 
  (`request_user_id`, `request_rest_item_id`, `request_amount`) 
VALUES (23, 7, 3),(35,10,23),(2,4,99)
 on duplicate key
 update `request_amount`=`request_amount`+values(`request_amount`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add column name + new value.

```
INSERT INTO `tblrequests` (`request_user_id`, `request_rest_item_id`, `request_amount`) VALUES (23, 7, 3)
 on duplicate key
 update `request_amount`=values(`request_amount` + 3);
```

Comment: the problem is they are not clear values like in my example, the insert is getting the value from another select statement. sorry that i wasn't clear.

Comment: @medoampir, post your select query too.

Comment: @MShahzadKhan Yes I know. I'm just referring to the possibility of eliminating the `values` syntax from _your_ query. Is it really necessary?

Comment: @geomagas. Oh yeah, no not neccessary. :)